# Get rid of cached data from FlutterBlue BLE Scanning?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm using FlutterBlue to find my devices... but I keep getting "old" results; if I power off my device, I still get "advertisement packets" in the phone from the device when it was on...

I'd like to say "give me only what you hear on the air" so that if the time since I last heard from the device was > 5 seconds, I'll -200 the rssi and gray it out...

But I keep getting these "cached" packets that keeps clearing my timer...

My line to start the scanner is:
`await flutterBlue.startScan(allowDuplicates: true);`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I currently am getting inconsistent results when scanning using FlutterBluePlus which I suspect is due to some caching of previously found peripherals. If you found a solution, please post as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not so much.  It helps if you do the scan and throw out the first 5 seconds or so and wait for more to come in.  It also helps if you use the data (if any) from the Advertisement packets (so, in my devices I use the "LocalName" attribute) as those come in reliably instead of cached...